# how to set containerd in offline.yml at old version of kubespray

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, kubespray

In the new **Kubespray** release **containerd** is set as default, but the old one isn't.

I want to change docker to containerd in old version and install it with that version.

When I looked the `offline.yml` I don't see any option for **containerd** in **Redhat**. Below is the code from `offline.yml`:

```
# CentOS/Redhat/AlmaLinux/Rocky Linux
## Docker / Containerd
docker_rh_repo_base_url: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/$releasever/$basearch"
docker_rh_repo_gpgkey: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/gpg"

# Fedora
## Docker
docker_fedora_repo_base_url: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/{{ ansible_architecture }}"
docker_fedora_repo_gpgkey: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/gpg"
## Containerd
containerd_fedora_repo_base_url: "{{ yum_repo }}/containerd"
containerd_fedora_repo_gpgkey: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/gpg"

# Debian
## Docker
docker_debian_repo_base_url: "{{ debian_repo }}/docker-ce"
docker_debian_repo_gpgkey: "{{ debian_repo }}/docker-ce/gpg"
## Containerd
containerd_debian_repo_base_url: "{{ ubuntu_repo }}/containerd"
containerd_debian_repo_gpgkey: "{{ ubuntu_repo }}/containerd/gpg"
containerd_debian_repo_repokey: 'YOURREPOKEY'

# Ubuntu
## Docker
docker_ubuntu_repo_base_url: "{{ ubuntu_repo }}/docker-ce"
docker_ubuntu_repo_gpgkey: "{{ ubuntu_repo }}/docker-ce/gpg"
## Containerd
containerd_ubuntu_repo_base_url: "{{ ubuntu_repo }}/containerd"
containerd_ubuntu_repo_gpgkey: "{{ ubuntu_repo }}/containerd/gpg"
containerd_ubuntu_repo_repokey: 'YOURREPOKEY'
```

How should I set containerd in `offline.ym`l and how to find which version of containerd is stable with this Kubespray?

Thanks for answering

Comment: I have found a fragment of offline.yml from Jan 25, 2021. See [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/commit/8f2b0772f9ca2d146438638e1fb9f7484cbdbd55#:~:text=calicoctl%2Dlinux%2D%7B%7B%20image_arch%20%7D%7D%22-,%23%20CentOS/Redhat,extras_rh_repo_gpgkey%3A%20%22%7B%7B%20yum_repo%20%7D%7D/containerd/gpg%22,-%23%20Fedora). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Always try to dig in history in documentation. Since you're looking for outdated version see [this fragment](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/commit/8f2b0772f9ca2d146438638e1fb9f7484cbdbd55#:%7E:text=calicoctl%2Dlinux%2D%7B%7B%20image_arch%20%7D%7D%22-,%23%20CentOS/Redhat,extras_rh_repo_gpgkey%3A%20%22%7B%7B%20yum_repo%20%7D%7D/containerd/gpg%22,-%23%20Fedora) of offline.yaml:

```yaml
# CentOS/Redhat
## Docker
## Docker / Containerd
docker_rh_repo_base_url: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/$releasever/$basearch"
docker_rh_repo_gpgkey: "{{ yum_repo }}/docker-ce/gpg"

## Containerd
extras_rh_repo_base_url: "{{ yum_repo }}/centos/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/extras/$basearch"
extras_rh_repo_gpgkey: "{{ yum_repo }}/containerd/gpg"
```

Reference: [*kubespray documentation*](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray).

Comment: Thanks for answering. May i ask one more question ? I can find yum repo of containerd but How i find or create gpg  for it ?